# OO Programming: Summary of objects

Tags: oop

I want to have two classes that are independent of each other. A content type and a URL. A URL will have a conent type.

Could I add into the content type a summary field, which could be easily queried (e.g content type X has 10 URL's) or would I need to query all of the URL's and pull out the content type that way?

A URL can also be associated with other classes (not just this content type), which is why I don't create a superclass of content type, and then a sub URL class.

Answer (score 0):

That depends. Basically what you are asking is the following: Given a 1:n relationship, how can I automatically query both directions?

If you use a database to store your data, most object-relational mappers give you this functionality for free. If you don't, you need to handle it yourself.

There are various options. The most simplistic approach is to iterate all URLs and filter the ones that match the queried content type. This is most likely the responsibility of some container. This variant is very easy to implement but takes `O(number of URLs)` time to execute the query. So if you just have a few URLs, this may be the way to go.

The other option is to explicitly store the inverse relationship. Either directly in the content types or in a container (e.g. within a hash map). The main problem of this approach is keeping both pairs of a relationship in sync. You could use the setter of the URL's content type property to update the content type's URLs property. The task of synchronizing the relationships could also be handed over to a container. Anyway, this option is significantly faster but requires some programming effort. Depending on your concrete scenario, this might be more or less work.